# Custom OSX window skin?

Tags: objective-c, macos, user-interface, skinning, nswindow

How do I make custom buttons for my app window on OSX? I'd also like to skin the entire window.

Are there any easy classes or ways to do this? Any tutorials that show how?

Comment: Mac users normally don't like that.

Comment: @swegi - Why not? (Just curious)

Comment: Because we like to have consistency in our UI. You may want to read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGIntro/XHIGIntro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deviate a little from the standard OS X interface, you should take a look at `NSThemeFrame`, the class that draws standard OS X windows. You can read a little bit about it [here](http://parmanoir.com/Custom_NSThemeFrame), and find out more using Google.

Answer (score 0):

CocoaWithLove has an [article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html) that describes how to make your own window:

[image: custom window]